# Foreman asks for Ruby 2.1.1, but it is already installed. How do I fix this error?

Tags: ruby, rvm, foreman, fish

```
~/D/R/appname> foreman run rails c
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1
~/D/R/appname> rvm install 2.1.1
Already installed ruby-2.1.1.
To reinstall use:

    rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.1

~/D/R/appname> foreman run rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
[1] pry(main)>
```

When I run `foreman run rails c` or `foreman run rails s`, I get a message, `'Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1'`.  When I install that version with rvm, I get a message that it is already installed.  After running the rvm install command, and then running foreman again, everything is fine.

How do I fix this error?  Note that I am using the Fish shell.

.ruby-version file:

```
2.1.1
```

Top of Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'pg'
```

Comment: try `rvm use 2.1.1`, and if this works, you can also look to set it as default here - https://rvm.io/rubies/default

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have to switch to ruby 2.1 before run foreman.

```
rvm use 2.1.1
```

To avoid running this command every time, you can:

- Set this version as default - this way every time you open the console RVM will use 2.1.1 instead of 2.0.0.

  rvm use 2.1.1 --default
- Create a ruby version file inside your directory: This time RVM will magically switch ruby version for you when you are in this directory.

  echo "ruby-2.1.1-pyourpathversion" > .ruby-version

The last one will only work with newer RVMs, but since you installed 2.1.1, it should work for you.

Comment: @UriAgassi I'm not sure it works without the full thing - ruby prefix and patchlevel postfix. I already had problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.
Ruby 2.1.1 specified in Gemfile and .ruby-version.

the foreman gem was installed globally, but not in the current gemset.
This fixed it:

```
    echo "gem 'foreman'" >> Gemfile && bundle
```